# bitwise-operators in Python

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators

Maybe this is a beginner's question. But I need someone who explain  me (breaking in steps) how with this bitwise-operator I call all values ​​of `X_test`

```
X_train_01_subset= X_train [(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)]
```

`X_train` is a 105x2 samples vector and `y_train` is a 105x1 label vector.

Comment: these operators are not acting as *bitwise* operators per se. They are *vectorized* (i.e. elementwise) boolean operators on numpy arrays, that return boolean arrays, which can be used to index another array.

Comment: Objects can define themselves how they "respond" to operators, and numpy is overloading operators a fair bit for a lot of "magical" behaviour.